# What does "$.something" mean in jquery?

Tags: jquery

i find it everywhere, like this.

```
function($) {
  $.test = { some code }
}
```

what does it mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should think about jQuery code as a division between two ways of calling functions:

1. Methods on selections. This is the standard "find some elements, do something with them" technique. It's code like [`$('p').val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val), [`$('div').prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend), etc.
2. Methods without selections. These are functions that don't require you to do a selection before calling a function.  These are functions like [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax), [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param), [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each).  For the sake of convenience, they are properties of the global variable `$`, which is the jQuery library. Often, they aren't jQuery-specific, but are useful pieces of code to include in the library.

Comment: Nailed it. I had only written stuff like $('selector').do_something. It seems clear to me, now, that $.stuff creates new methods for jquery objects :)

Answer (score 9):

Think of `$` just like any other variable. For jQuery, it's the jQuery object, which is pretty powerful. But it's just like any other variable; you could write your own `$` if you wanted to, for example.

It's an unusual variable name, yes, but there's nothing magical about it. The `.something` is just a property of the variable `$`. It's no different than writing `obj.something`, except the variable name is `$` instead.

The other non-alphanumeric character you can use in JavaScript as a variable name is `_` (the underscore). It's used in some other libraries, like [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) . But again, there's nothing special about using `_`.

Comment: `$` is a standard used for variables in various other languages. There's nothing magical about it.

Comment: i had seen $variables before, but it was the first time i saw $ all by itself.

Comment: I don't know if the `$` is the _chicken_ or the _egg_.... but I often can't help but wonder if it might not just BE the `$` that makes JS... "so f-ing annoying".

Answer (score 4):

the $ variable is an alias to the jQuery object / 'namespace'.  So you when you see `$.function()` you are actually calling a method named 'function' on the jQuery object.  In your example code provided an object named `test` is being attached to the jQuery object.  if you wrote `$.test = function() { }` you would be attaching a function (method) instead of an object.

Answer (score 2):

Go read the jQuery [API](http://api.jquery.com/) and [tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) on their websites.

In particular ["How it works"](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aHow_jQuery_Works) and ["Plugin Authoring"](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring). As your code sample looks like a jQuery plugin